# What's the purpose of a ravaged battleship I found on my map?

Tags: a-dark-room

I can't find any information on it online (on the map it is signified with an X). I went in and got a whirring fabricator after beating some enemies, any info?
I went into a room called engineering and got a blueprint for an item called hypos that can be crafted with the whirring fabricator for 1 alien alloy (you get 5) I also got a kinetic Armor blueprint from engineering (2 alien alloy)

I can also craft:

- an energy blade (deals 10 damage) (1 alien alloy)
- a fluid recycler (2 alien alloy)
- a cargo drone (2 alien alloy)

Comment: In which website are you playing this? I don't remember any of the craftable items you mentioned here in the game.

Comment: https://adarkroom.doublespeakgames.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all part of brand new content added in celebration of A Dark Room's 10th anniversary! Explore, get new gear, fight some cool bosses, and maybe even learn some secret lore.

Thanks for playing <3

Comment: Ah, so this is a new content, that's why I never heard of those items. @pinckerman seems like this Michael is [Michael Townsend](https://twitter.com/continuities), the creator of the game in question. From players perspective, given this information from the creator that this is a new thing, we would like to discover it ourselves first, I guess. The question was asked with the assumption that this was a known thing, but it's really a new thing, and that's probably why OP accepted this answer.

Comment: @justhalf didn't know that, if Micheal is the developer then is surely a valid answer LOL